# How to set a children compontent in vue.js to be shown as "default"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, web-frameworks

I have a project made in Vue.js 3, using vue-router with a configuration like this:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: "home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/philosophy',
    component: philosophy,
    children: [{
        path: '/',
        component: card1
      },
      {
        path: '/card2',
        component: card2
      },
      {
        path: '/card3',
        component: card3
      },
      {
        path: '/card4',
        component: card4
      }]
  }  
]
```

Every card is loaded via `router-link` directive, inside of a `<div>` element where there is a `rowter-view`.

The path of `card1` is `"/"` to intend the card1 to be loaded just when the user enters to the path "/philosophy". This works just fine in Vue 2, but not in Vue 3, where the component is not loaded anymore.
Is there any way in Vue 3 to make the component `card1` to be loaded *by defautl*?

Thanks beforehand for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the default path from '/' to empty string literal `""`. And then in the philosophy component add a `<router-view>` in the template to show the default component.

Routes:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/philosphy',
    component: philosophy,
    children: [{
        path: '',  //default view
        component: card1
      },
      {
        path: '/card2',
        component: card2
      },
      {
        path: '/card3',
        component: card3
      },
      {
        path: '/card4',
        component: card4
      }]
  }  
]
```

philosophy component:

```
 <template>
    <router-view>
    </template> 
    export default {
    name: "Philosophy"
  }
```

Comment: It works if he not use `:to=""` in navigation buttons.

Comment: @Mises I tried that, but it breaks the code, and nothing appears in the screen when calling the route '/philosophy'.  I used to="/philosophy" in the navigation button, it worked fine.

Comment: @SDEscobedo use `to="philosophy"`

Comment: @SDEscobedo You have miss speling in `path:`